# What are the three 255's before the image in a monochrome .bmp?

Tags: bmp

I'm trying to figure out bitmap formatting for a project I'm working on, but there's one thing I don't really get. In this .bmp:

```
00000000  42 4d aa 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 82 00 00 00 6c 00  |BM............l.|
00000010  00 00 0a 00 00 00 0a 00  00 00 01 00 01 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 28 00 00 00 13 0b  00 00 13 0b 00 00 02 00  |..(.............|
00000030  00 00 02 00 00 00 42 47  52 73 00 00 00 00 00 00  |......BGRs......|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 ff ff ff 00 00 00  |................|
00000080  00 00 ff c0 00 00 ff c0  00 00 ff c0 00 00 ff c0  |................|
*
000000a0  00 00 ff c0 00 00 aa 80  00 00                    |..........|
000000aa
```

what are the three 256's at offset 122 (line 7). I assume they're some sort of color indicators, but I'm not sure.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x22FP.png) is the image I'm using.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top part of your hex dump is a "BITMAPINFO structure" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183375(v=vs.85).aspx). This is immediately followed by a color index array `bmiColors` (although its length may be `0`, and you should check this in the `BITMAPINFO` data).

Although some say that

> [t]hough seemingly a simple format, it is complicated by its many different versions, lack of an official specification, lack of any version control process, and ambiguities and contradictions in the documentation.
>   (http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/BMP)

you don't *actually* need to understand each single byte. The various structures either have a fixed size (the initial `BITMAPFILEHEADER` for example), or have their length as its first value.

A line by line annotation of most well-documented parts:

```
--------  BITMAPFILEHEADER
00000000  42 4d          file type identifier
00000002  aa 00 00 00    size in bytes of the entire file
00000006  00 00          (reserved and must be 0)
00000008  00 00          (reserved and must be 0)
0000000A  82 00 00 00    offset from the beginning of the BITMAPFILEHEADER structure to the bitmap bits

--------  BITMAPINFOHEADER
0000000E  6c 00 00 00    BITMAPINFOHEADER structure size
00000012  0a 00 00 00    image width in pixels
00000016  0a 00 00 00    image height in pixels
0000001A  01 00          number of planes
0000001C  01 00          number of bits per pixel
0000001E  00 00 00 00    compression
00000022  28 00 00 00    size in bytes of image data
00000026  13 0b 00 00    horizontal resolution in pixels-per-meter
0000002A  13 0b 00 00    vertical resolution in pixels-per-meter
0000002E  02 00 00 00    number of colors in the color table that are actually used by the bitmap
00000032  02 00 00 00    number of color indexes that are required ("important")

........ badly documented stuff ........
00000036  42 47 52 73 00 00 00 00 00 00
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
--------  end of BITMAPINFOHEADER

--------  bmiColors array
0000007A  ff ff ff 00    color table entry #0
0000007E  00 00 00 00    color table entry #1

--------  Image data
00000082  ff c0 00 00 ff c0 00 00 ff c0 00 00 ff c0
000000a0  00 00 ff c0 00 00 aa 80 00 00
```

The "number of bits per pixel" at `0000001C` is 1:

> "1 = The bitmap is monochrome, and the bmiColors member of BITMAPINFO contains two entries. Each bit in the bitmap array represents a pixel. If the bit is clear, the pixel is displayed with the color of the first entry in the bmiColors table; if the bit is set, the pixel has the color of the second entry in the table."
>   (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx)

and the number of colors in the array is reported to be 2. So the `bmiColors` array contains 2 elements in Microsoft's `RGBQUAD` format, with values in the odd order Blue, Green, Red, and Reserved.

In short: in your image, a pixel value of `0` (a 0 bit in a monochrome image) is `FFFFFF`: white, and a pixel value of `1` is `000000`: black.